# OpenMP - sections

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I wrote an application using OpenMP. I created two sections and put into them two objects. Each of them calls a method which is running nearly 22-23 seconds. Both sections are independent.

When I set `num_threads(1)`, the application takes 46 seconds to run. That's ok, because 2×23=46.

When I set `num_threads(2)`, the application takes 35 seconds to run, but I was expecting ~25 seconds.

As I said, the sections are independent. `cm1` and `cm2` don't use any external variables. So, could anyone tell me why my app is 10 seconds slower than I expected? Is there any synchronization on low level?

```
t1 = clock();
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
    #pragma omp sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            Cam cm1;
            cm1.solveUsingCost();
        }

        #pragma omp section
        {
            Cam cm2;
            cm2.solveUsingTime();
        }
    }
}
t2 = clock();
```

Comment: I hope you know that `clock()` measures the CPU time and not the real (or wallclock) time.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter here. I could use my stopwatch and I still could see difference.

Comment: It's just a remark for others reading your question - most people using `clock()` instead of `omp_get_wtime()` never see any speedup from using OpenMP :) As to your speedup problem - Intel VTune (commercial license required on Windows) or similar performance tool which records hardware performance counters can help you a lot with threading performance issues.

Comment: In addition to Intel VTune which can shed a lot of light into the bottlenecks, you can also first try [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) or [callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) to get a quick sense of what's going on before bringing in the big guns (VTune).
perf is Linux, don't know your dev environment...

Answer (score 2):

How many CPUs or cores do you have? If for example you have only 2 physical cores, one of them will also have to process all other programm + OS therefore this will slow down one of the threads.

Another possibility is that the L3 chache of your CPU is sufficent to save the data of one calculation at a time completly in L3 cache. But when doing 2 in paralell the double amount of memory is used and therefore maybe some memory from the L3 cache has to be transfered to the ram (Note that most Multicore CPUs share L3 cache between the cores). This will slow down your calculations a lot and could lead to the described results.

However these are only guesses, there could be a lot further reasons why there is not factor 2 speed gain, when doing your calculation in parallel.

Update:
Of course what I forgot until you mentioned your CPU being an i5: i5 and i7 processors have this "Turbo boost" called ability to increase thier clock speed, in your case from 3.3 to 3.6 GHz. This however is only done when most cores are in idle (for thermal reasons I think) and a single core is boosted. Therefore two cores will not have double the speed of one core because they will run at lower clock speed.

Comment: Ok, then it should not be my first guess. Do you approximately know how much memory is needed by your calculation? Quick search said your CPU has 6 mb of shared L3 cache.

Comment: Yes, my i5 has 6MB L3. In Task Manager my application is using max 27MB.

Comment: Even if Turbo boost is on I don't believe that time could be so long. It's nearly 10seconds more than I expected.

Comment: You might also want to look into [False Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing), especially if `sizeof(Cam) <= 32` and `Cam` contains some result variable(s) that are frequently accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your replies to the previous answer and comments, my guess is that your two functions, `solveUsingCost()` and `solveUsingTime()`, are quite memory-intensive or at least memory bandwidth limited.

What exactly are you computing? And how? What is, roughly, the ratio of arithmetic operations per memory access? How is your memory access patterned, e.g. do you run through a large array several times?